# How do I send push notifications from one device to another with React Native using Expo and Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, expo, stripe-payments

I want my Android app to send push notifications from one device to another. I've connected the project to Firebase and can send a push notification to myself via the Expo push notification tool. I am confused on how to use Firebase to relay a message from one device to another. I've read through the expo docs but am confused as to what my next step should be. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code so far.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as Device from 'expo-device';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: false,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});


// Can use this function below or use Expo's Push Notification Tool from: https://expo.dev/notifications
async function sendPushNotification(expoPushToken) {
  const message = {
    to: expoPushToken,
    sound: 'default',
    title: 'Original Title',
    body: 'And here is the body!',
    // data: { someData: 'goes here' },
  };


  await fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(message),
  });
}

async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;
  if (Device.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
      return;
    }
    token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
      projectId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId,
    });
    console.log(token);
  } else {
    alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    });
  }

  return token;
}


export default function App() {
  const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState('');
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState(false);
  const notificationListener = useRef();
  const responseListener = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(token => setExpoPushToken(token));

    notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
      setNotification(notification);
    });

    responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });

    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
       {/* <Text>Your expo push token: {expoPushToken}</Text> */}
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>{notification && notification.request.content.title} </Text>
        <Text>{notification && notification.request.content.body}</Text>
        {/* <Text>Data: {notification && JSON.stringify(notification.request.content.data)}</Text> */}
      </View>
      <Button
        title="Press to Send Notification"
        onPress={async () => {
          await sendPushNotification(expoPushToken);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can check this post on medium, I think it is a nice one https://medium.com/@arashfallahi1989/how-to-integrate-firebase-push-notification-in-react-native-expo-bd5cc694f181